# mod_wsgi-express randomly restarting/crashing

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm using mod_wsgi-express to serve a simple Flask app on a CentOS 6 server. The app is currently used pretty infrequently.

I'm having an issue where every few days, the app will crash, either serving up 500 errors or not responding at all. This doesn't seem related to load or use.

Looking through the error log, I'm seeing occasional "**[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down**" messages, after which it appears mod_wsgi-express restarts. I don't know why this is happening.

I'm also getting this message:

> [error] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=24550, process='localhost:8080', application=''): Call to fopen() failed ff
>   or '/tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8080:14699/handler.wsgi'.

I've tried running mod_wsgi-express with both gdb and pdb debuggers enabled and haven't seen any bugs related to the actual execution of the Python script.

I also got a

> [info] [client 137.78.237.31] (104)Connection reset by peer: core_output_filter: writing data to the network

which kicked off hundreds of

> [notice] child pid 15952 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

over the course of a couple days.

These messages all seem to happen randomly and independent of each other. **The only consistent thing is the SIGTERM signal happening every so often.**

I'm confused as to what's going on. The implementation seems pretty simple - it's a simple tool that validates metadata in an uploaded file.

Comment: When using gdb mode, are you also supplying ``--debug-mode``? The gdb mode will only work when in debug mode and suspect you wouldn't be doing that in a long running instance as it restricts it to single process and single thread to allow debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For the 500 errors, use the `--server-root` option to specify a directory other than in the default of `/tmp` for its working directory.

The default should only be used for short runs and `--server-root` used to specify a more permanent home if running it for longer periods.

This is necessary as some operating systems can be set up to remove files from `/tmp` when they haven't been modified for some period. I have been contemplating adding a warning in the startup output specifically to suggest use of `--server-root` if the default is being relied upon.

For the segmentation fault issue, please come over the mod_wsgi mailing list to discuss further. StackOverflow is not a discussion forum and that issue will likely need more investigation and discussion to understand what your application is doing.

---

UPDATE 1

Discussion continuing at:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/NmyOtp-9Pmg